# Spring DomainClassConverter Cache

Tags: spring, caching, spring-data-jpa

I'm using spring-data-jpa, and I'm trying to apply spring cache abstraction.
`findByEmail()` method caches well, however, user variable on `retrieve()` method at controller which spring-data-jpa provide `DomainClassConverter` always looks up DB.

In documentation, it calles `findOne()` to look up the resource, but the `@Cacheable` trigger won't work.
It seems like implementation class as `SimpleJpaRepository` just invoke `CrudRepository` instead of `UserRepository` which I created and put `@Cacheable` annotation.

Is there any way to apply `@Cacheable` to `findOne()` except for custom `DomainClassConverter` class ?

UserController.class

```
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET, value = "/users/{user}")
    public ResponseEntity retrieve(@PathVariable User user) {
        logger.info("Retrieve: " + user);

        return new ResponseEntity(user.toUserResponse(), HttpStatus.OK);
    }
```

UserService.class

```
public interface UserRepository extends JpaRepository<User, Long>, JpaSpecificationExecutor<User> {
    @Cacheable("Users")
    User findOne(Long id);

    @Cacheable("Users")
    User findByEmail(String email);

    User findByEmailAndPassword(String email, String password);

    Long countByEmail(String email);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've filed and fixed [DATACMNS-620](https://jira.spring.io/browse/DATACMNS-620) for you.

This issue shouldn't actually occur with Spring Data Commons 1.10.0 M1 (Fowler) as we moved to the Spring Data REST `RepositoryInvoker`API which explicitly checked for custom overrides. I created a fix for the 1.9.x bugfix branch so that we fix this for users of the current release train Evans.

If you want to check this upgrade to Spring Data Commons 1.9.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT or 1.10.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT. If you're using Boot, you can simply set a property `spring-data-releasetrain.version` and set it to either `Evans-BUILD-SNAPSHOT` or `Fowler-BUILD-SNAPSHOT`.

Comment: I really appreciate it @Oliver Gierke, I was gonna disable `DomainClassConverter` and make a custom annotation that gets object from db using overridden `findOne()` to make sure using cache. Thanks for your time to create an issue for me and I will look forward the next version.